# JHipster default Authentication Failure

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

I have created a new project with JHipster and everything was going OK. I could log in by using default username/password (admin/admin) and then I generated my classes using JDL Studio.
After that, I couldn't log in anymore.However, I can Insert a new user.

This is the stacktrace:

> pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.errors.InternalServerErrorException: User could not be found
>       at pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.AccountResource.lambda$getAccount$25(AccountResource.java:107)
>       at pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.AccountResource$$Lambda$68/2111965665.get(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
>       at pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.AccountResource.getAccount(AccountResource.java:107)
>       at pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.AccountResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3f2c212e.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
>       at pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
>       at pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.AccountResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d82cd9b3.getAccount()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)...

and

> 18-02-26 15:02:29.431  WARN 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: http://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message{500, User could not be found}
>   2018-02-26 15:02:29.433 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /api/account ]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.625 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /api/authentication ]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.627 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /api/authentication
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.627 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/api/authentication]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.632 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /api/authentication ]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.634 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /error
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.635 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/error]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.657 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /api/logout ]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.659 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /api/logout
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.660 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/api/logout]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.662 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /api/logout ]
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.663 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /error
>   2018-02-26 15:02:48.663 DEBUG 6252 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/error]

I get a null result after getting the user. I copied the generated SQL and it actually gets the user. I don't have any idea why I can't acces.

Comment: From stacktrace, you an error 500 on server, this is not what you get when an entity cannot be found, so I suspect that there was an exception earlier you might have not noticed with real cause. Whhc version of JHipster?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I am using version v4.14.0

Comment: Also, got this :
p.g.m.sisfact.aop.logging.LoggingAspect  : Enter: pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.AccountResource.getAccount() with argument[s] = []
2018-02-26 18:31:13.409 DEBUG 10980 --- [  XNIO-2 task-4] p.g.m.sisfact.aop.logging.LoggingAspect  : Enter: pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.service.UserService.getUserWithAuthorities() with argument[s] = []
Exit: pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.service.UserService.getUserWithAuthorities() with result = Optional.empty
Exception in pe.gob.mindef.sisfact.web.rest.AccountResource.getAccount() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'User could not be found'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. But it got resolved by the command :

```
mvn clean install
```